# Windows phone performance progress bar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing app in Wp7 and i want to learn how to perform preformance progress bar in wp7 from basic.
I am Using windows phone toolkit to use performance progress bar..
How To Start And Stop it??

Answer (score 3):

Use the following to stop the animation and to hide the control from view:

```
myProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = False
myPragressBar.Visibility = Collapsed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
In Xaml :

```
<ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="progressBar1" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
```

and when you want to hide it from code then use

```
progressBar1.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

In .cs file:

```
  using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private ProgressIndicator _progressIndicator;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator
            {
                IsIndeterminate = true,
                Text = "Loading...",
                IsVisible = true,
            };

            SystemTray.SetIsVisible(this, true);
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, _progressIndicator);
            SystemTray.SetOpacity(this, 1);

            //something is a very long here

            _progressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            SystemTray.SetIsVisible(this, false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an Determinate Progress bar you can just do it like this:

```
<ProgressBar Value="25" ></ProgressBar>
```

This Progress bar is at 25%.

You can also Bind it to a Property in your ViewModel and maybe add a converter:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding MyProgress, Converter={StaticResource ProgressConverter}}" ></ProgressBar>
```